# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have added some changes on a project that i am currently working on. I had a single User class and 3 different profiles (admin,docteur,patient).

I have changed the structure of the project by adding two User subclasses (Docteur and Patient) and the profiles are User or admin.

**User**:

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USER")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "SSO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String ssoId;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
        private String password;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
        private String firstName;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
        private String lastName;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
        private String email;

        @Column(name = "DTCREATION", nullable = true)
        private String dateCreation;

        @Column(name = "JJCREATION", nullable = true)
        private String jjCreation;

        public String getJjCreation() {
            return jjCreation;
        }

        public void setJjCreation(String jjCreation) {
            this.jjCreation = jjCreation;
        }

        @Column(name = "MMCREATION", nullable = true)
        private String mmCreation;

        public String getMmCreation() {
            return mmCreation;
        }

        public void setMmCreation(String mmCreation) {
            this.mmCreation = mmCreation;
        }

        @Column(name = "YYCREATION", nullable = true)
        private String aaCreation;

        public String getAaCreation() {
            return aaCreation;
        }

        public void setAaCreation(String aaCreation) {
            this.aaCreation = aaCreation;
        }

        public String getDateCreation() {
            return dateCreation;
        }

        public void setDateCreation(String dateCreation) {
            this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        }

        @NotEmpty
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
        private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getSsoId() {
            return ssoId;
        }

        public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
            this.ssoId = ssoId;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
            return userProfiles;
        }

        public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
            this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((ssoId == null) ? 0 : ssoId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (!(obj instanceof User))
                return false;
            User other = (User) obj;
            if (id == null) {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
            if (ssoId == null) {
                if (other.ssoId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!ssoId.equals(other.ssoId))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User [id=" + id + ", ssoId=" + ssoId + ", password=" + password + ", firstName=" + firstName
                    + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
        }

    }
```

**Docteur**:

```
 package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "DOCTEUR")
    public class Docteur extends User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doc")
        private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<Patient>(0);

        public Set<Patient> getPatients() {
            return patients;
        }

        public void setPatients(Set<Patient> patients) {
            this.patients = patients;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
```

**Patient**:

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PATIENT")
public class Patient extends User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<Consultation> consultations = new HashSet<Consultation>(0);

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Docteur doc;

    public Docteur getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(Docteur doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public Set<Consultation> getConsultations() {
        return consultations;
    }

    public void setConsultations(Set<Consultation> consultations) {
        this.consultations = consultations;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Converter**:

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.converter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.UserProfile;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService;

/**
 * A converter class used in views to map id's to actual userProfile objects.
 */
@Component
public class RoleToUserProfileConverter implements Converter<Object, UserProfile>{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleToUserProfileConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    /**
     * Gets UserProfile by Id
     * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public UserProfile convert(Object element) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
        UserProfile profile= userProfileService.findById(id);
        logger.info("Profile : {}",profile);
        return profile;
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.controller;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.Consultation;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.User;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.UserProfile;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.UserProfileType;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.AppetitService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.BouleService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.ConsultationService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.DocteurService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.DouleurService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.FaiblesseService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.PatientService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserService;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.utils.Mail;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Autowired
    AppetitService appetitService;

    @Autowired
    FaiblesseService faiblesseService;

    @Autowired
    DouleurService douleurService;

    @Autowired
    BouleService bouleService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

    @Autowired
    ConsultationService consultationService;

    @Autowired
    PatientService patientService;

    @Autowired
    DocteurService docteurServices;

    /**
     * This method will list all existing users.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide the medium to add a new user.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newconsultation" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newConsultation(ModelMap model) {
        Consultation consultation = new Consultation();
        model.addAttribute("consultation", consultation);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registrationConsultation";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        if (!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())) {
            FieldError ssoError = new FieldError("user", "ssoId", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId",
                    new String[] { user.getSsoId() }, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssoError);
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);
        Mail.sendMailRegistration("support@xxxxxxx.net", user.getEmail(), "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
                "xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Creation de compte vivalio", "message");

        model.addAttribute("success",
                "User " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        // return "success";
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /* ajouter la consultation du patient */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newconsultation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveConsultation(@Valid Consultation consultation, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registrationConsultation";
        }
        // Patient patient = (Patient) getUser();
        consultation.setPatient(null);
        consultationService.saveConsultation(consultation);

        if (consultation != null && consultation.getPatient() != null) {
            Mail.sendMailAfterConsultation("support@xxxxxxx.net", consultation.getPatient().getEmail(),
                    "xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "Envoi de la consultation a votre medecin : ",
                    "Votre consultation REF-" + consultation.getId()
                            + " a ete envoyee a votre medecin avec succes. Vous serez contacte en cas d'urgence.<br/>Ci dessous un recap de votre consultation :<br/>"
                            + "<br/>Poid : " + consultation.getParam1() + "<br/>" + "Appetit :"
                            + consultation.getParam2() + "<br/>" + "Faiblesse :" + consultation.getParam3() + "<br/>"
                            + "Douleur :" + consultation.getParam4() + "<br/>" + "Boule :" + consultation.getParam5()
                            + "<br/>" + "Fievre :" + consultation.getParam6() + "<br/>" + "Commentaire :"
                            + consultation.getCommentaire() + "<br/>" + "<br/>L'equipe vivalio Group"

            );
        }

        model.addAttribute("param1", consultation.getParam1());
        model.addAttribute("param2", consultation.getParam2());
        model.addAttribute("param3", consultation.getParam3());

        model.addAttribute("param4", consultation.getParam4());
        model.addAttribute("param5", consultation.getParam5());
        model.addAttribute("param6", consultation.getParam6());
        model.addAttribute("commentaire", consultation.getCommentaire());

        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide the medium to update an existing user.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable String ssoId, ModelMap model) {
        User user = userService.findBySSO(ssoId);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssoId) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.updateUser(user);
        Mail.sendMailRegistration("support@xxxxx.net", user.getEmail(), "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
                "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "Modification des informations vivalio",
                "Votre utilisateur vivalio a été modifié");

        model.addAttribute("success",
                "User " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /**
     * This method will delete an user by it's SSOID value.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String ssoId) {
        userService.deleteUserBySSO(ssoId);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide UserProfile list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<UserProfile> initializeProfiles() {
        return userProfileService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide Docs list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("docteurs")
    public List<User> initializeAllDocs() {
        return userService.findAllDocs();
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide Appetit list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("appetits")
    public List<String> initializeAppetits() {
        return appetitService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide Faiblesse list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("faiblesses")
    public List<String> initializeFaiblesses() {
        return faiblesseService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide Douleur list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("douleurs")
    public List<String> initializeDouleurs() {
        return douleurService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide Boules list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("boules")
    public List<String> initializeBoules() {
        return bouleService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method handles Access-Denied redirect.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            // new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response,
            // auth);
            persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.logout(request, response, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the principal[user-name] of logged-in user.
     */
    private String getPrincipal() {
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private User getUser() {
        String username = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        User usr = userService.findBySSO(username);
        return usr;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns true if users is already authenticated [logged-in],
     * else false.
     */
    private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }

    /**
     * This method will redirect to dashboard
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/board" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tableauBord(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();

        // TOTAL des utilisateurs de la base
        int totalAdmin = userService.findAllAdmins().size();
        int totalDocs = userService.findAllDocs().size();
        int totalPatients = userService.findAllPatients().size();
        // ANNEE COURANTE
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        StringBuilder sbyear = new StringBuilder();
        sbyear.append(year);
        // RECHERCHER LES COMPTES PAR TYPE DE L'ANNEE EN COURS
        List<Object[]> totalComptesAdminParMois = userService
                .findAllUsersByTypeAndyear(UserProfileType.ADMINISTRATEUR.getUserProfileType(), sbyear.toString());
        List<Object[]> totalComptesDocParMois = userService
                .findAllUsersByTypeAndyear(UserProfileType.ADMINISTRATEUR.getUserProfileType(), sbyear.toString());
        List<Object[]> totalComptesPatParMois = userService
                .findAllUsersByTypeAndyear(UserProfileType.UTILISATEUR.getUserProfileType(), sbyear.toString());

        return "board";
    }

}
```

I have the error in the message object when trying to restart the server.

**AppConfig**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vivalio.springmvc")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    RoleToUserProfileConverter roleToUserProfileConverter;


    /**
     * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
     */
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    /**
     * Configure Converter to be used.
     * In our example, we need a converter to convert string values[Roles] to UserProfiles in newUser.jsp
     */
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(roleToUserProfileConverter);
    }


    /**
     * Configure MessageSource to lookup any validation/error message in internationalized property files
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /**Optional. It's only required when handling '.' in @PathVariables which otherwise ignore everything after last '.' in @PathVaidables argument.
     * It's a known bug in Spring [https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6164], still present in Spring 4.1.7.
     * This is a workaround for this issue.
     */
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field:
>   com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter
>   com.vivalio.springmvc.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileService
>   com.vivalio.springmvc.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.UserProfileDao
>   com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.vivalio.springmvc.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/vivalio/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

Comment: To understand the problem - configuration class and stacktrace is needed.

Comment: @badaboum, provide the code where appConfig bean is being used and bean definition code as well

Comment: @J-Alex i have added the stack trace and the configuration class

Comment: @AnilKumarAthuluri i have added the appConfig class and the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the root cause of the exception:

```
org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
```

Which means you have `@Id` in both child and parent classes.

Remove `@Id` field from both child classes, they will inherit it from the parent.

The second issue is that you have `@JoinColumn` with the same name as `@Id`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "doc_id") // give some unique column name here
private Docteur doc;
```

---

*P.S. Little advice not related to the issue:*

You have 10+ `@Autowired` dependencies in your `Controller`. It's really not a good way to design classes. Everytime observing too much `@Autowired` dependencies in one class should trigger you to think about you application design - this class takes too much responsibilities.

Comment: after deleting the Id field from the two subclasses i still have the following error : 

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.vivalio.springmvc.model.Patient column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: here is the stacktrace : 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/vivalio/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.vivalio.springmvc.model.Patient column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.

Comment: i am having the following error while trying to authenticate assuming that i have just two users in my database with different ids :
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.vivalio.springmvc.model.User] : Discriminator: 
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getInstanceClass(Loader.java:1770)

Comment: You definitely should post a new question, it's hard to understand it from comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493504/object-id-1-was-not-of-the-specified-subclass-com-vivalio-springmvc-model-use