# Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.vivalio.springmvc.model.User] : Discriminator:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am having an issue authenticating to my Spring mvc based web application after declaring two subclasses that inherit from the User Class like the following:

**User**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "SSO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String ssoId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "DTCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String dateCreation;

    @Column(name = "JJCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String jjCreation;

    public String getJjCreation() {
        return jjCreation;
    }

    public void setJjCreation(String jjCreation) {
        this.jjCreation = jjCreation;
    }

    @Column(name = "MMCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String mmCreation;

    public String getMmCreation() {
        return mmCreation;
    }

    public void setMmCreation(String mmCreation) {
        this.mmCreation = mmCreation;
    }

    @Column(name = "YYCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String aaCreation;

    public String getAaCreation() {
        return aaCreation;
    }

    public void setAaCreation(String aaCreation) {
        this.aaCreation = aaCreation;
    }

    public String getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(String dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSsoId() {
        return ssoId;
    }

    public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
        this.ssoId = ssoId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfiles;
    }

    public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
        this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((ssoId == null) ? 0 : ssoId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof User))
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (ssoId == null) {
            if (other.ssoId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ssoId.equals(other.ssoId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * DO-NOT-INCLUDE passwords in toString function. It is done here just for
     * convenience purpose.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", ssoId=" + ssoId + ", password=" + password + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

**Docteur**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCTEUR")
public class Docteur extends User implements Serializable {


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doc")
    private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<Patient>(0);

    public Set<Patient> getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }

    public void setPatients(Set<Patient> patients) {
        this.patients = patients;
    }


}
```

**Patient**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PATIENT")
public class Patient extends User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<Consultation> consultations = new HashSet<Consultation>(0);

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id")
    private Docteur doc;

    public Docteur getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(Docteur doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }




}
```

**Consultation**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONSULTATION")
public class Consultation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CONSID")
    private Integer id;

    // poid
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PARAM1", nullable = false)
    private String param1;

    // appetit
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PARAM2", nullable = false)
    private String param2;

    // faiblesse
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PARAM3", nullable = false)
    private String param3;

    // douleur
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PARAM4", nullable = false)
    private String param4;

    // boule
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PARAM5", nullable = false)
    private String param5;

    // fievre
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PARAM6", nullable = false)
    private String param6;

    // Commentaire
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "COMMENTAIRE", nullable = false)
    private String commentaire;

    @Column(name = "DTCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String dateCreation;

    @Column(name = "JJCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String jjCreation;

    @Column(name = "MMCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String mmCreation;

    @Column(name = "YYCREATION", nullable = true)
    private String aaCreation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Patient patient;

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public String getParam3() {
        return param3;
    }

    public void setParam3(String param3) {
        this.param3 = param3;
    }

    public String getParam4() {
        return param4;
    }

    public void setParam4(String param4) {
        this.param4 = param4;
    }

    public String getParam5() {
        return param5;
    }

    public void setParam5(String param5) {
        this.param5 = param5;
    }

    public String getParam6() {
        return param6;
    }

    public void setParam6(String param6) {
        this.param6 = param6;
    }

    public String getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(String dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public String getJjCreation() {
        return jjCreation;
    }

    public void setJjCreation(String jjCreation) {
        this.jjCreation = jjCreation;
    }

    public String getMmCreation() {
        return mmCreation;
    }

    public void setMmCreation(String mmCreation) {
        this.mmCreation = mmCreation;
    }

    public String getAaCreation() {
        return aaCreation;
    }

    public void setAaCreation(String aaCreation) {
        this.aaCreation = aaCreation;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCommentaire() {
        return commentaire;
    }

    public void setCommentaire(String commentaire) {
        this.commentaire = commentaire;
    }
}
```

on the database side, i have the following User table that contains User accounts.
[image]

Is it normal that the tables Patient and Docteur are not created ?

Iam having the following problem while trying to authenticate :

> Aug 03, 2017 8:34:00 PM
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
>   doFilter SEVERE: An internal error occurred while trying to
>   authenticate the user.
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException:
>   Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass
>   [com.vivalio.springmvc.model.User] : Discriminator:   at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)

And the image of the error :

[image]

**

### Security

**
**CustomUserDetail**
    package com.vivalio.springmvc.security;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.User;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.model.UserProfile;
import com.vivalio.springmvc.service.UserService;


@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findBySSO(ssoId);
        logger.info("User : {}", user);
        if(user==null){
            logger.info("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getSsoId(), user.getPassword(), 
                 true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }


    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfiles()){
            logger.info("UserProfile : {}", userProfile);
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userProfile.getType()));
        }
        logger.info("authorities : {}", authorities);
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/list")
                // .access("hasRole('DOCTEUR') or hasRole('ADMINISTRATEUR') or
                // hasRole('PATIENT')")
                .access("hasRole('ADMINISTRATEUR') OR hasRole('PATIENT') OR hasRole('DOCTEUR')").antMatchers("/board")
                .access("hasRole('ADMINISTRATEUR') ").antMatchers("/newconsultation")
                .access("hasRole('PATIENT')").antMatchers("/newuser/**", "/delete-user-*")
                .access("hasRole('ADMINISTRATEUR')").antMatchers("/edit-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMINISTRATEUR') ")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .tokenRepository(tokenRepository).tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

}
```

**Init**

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.security;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

In the controller i have the /login service

```
package com.vivalio.springmvc.controller

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Autowired
    AppetitService appetitService;

    @Autowired
    FaiblesseService faiblesseService;

    @Autowired
    DouleurService douleurService;

    @Autowired
    BouleService bouleService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

    @Autowired
    ConsultationService consultationService;

    @Autowired
    PatientService patientService;

    @Autowired
    DocteurService docteurServices;

    /**
     * This method will list all existing users.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide the medium to add a new user.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide the medium to add a new consultation.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newconsultation" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newConsultation(ModelMap model) {
        Consultation consultation = new Consultation();
        model.addAttribute("consultation", consultation);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registrationConsultation";
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
     * saving user in database. It also validates the user input
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        /*
         * Preferred way to achieve uniqueness of field [sso] should be
         * implementing custom @Unique annotation and applying it on field [sso]
         * of Model class [User].
         * 
         * Below mentioned peace of code [if block] is to demonstrate that you
         * can fill custom errors outside the validation framework as well while
         * still using internationalized messages.
         * 
         */
        if (!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())) {
            FieldError ssoError = new FieldError("user", "ssoId", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId",
                    new String[] { user.getSsoId() }, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssoError);
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);
        Mail.sendMailRegistration("support@xxxx.net", user.getEmail(), "aa.xxxx@gmail.com",
                "aa.xxxx@gmail.com", "Creation de compte vivalio", "message");

        model.addAttribute("success",
                "User " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        // return "success";
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /* ajouter la consultation du patient */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newconsultation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveConsultation(@Valid Consultation consultation, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registrationConsultation";
        }
        Patient patient = (Patient) getUser();
        //consultation.setPatient(null);
        consultationService.saveConsultation(consultation);

        if (consultation != null //&& 
                //consultation.getPatient() != null
                ) {
            Mail.sendMailAfterConsultation("support@vivalio.net", 
                    //consultation.getPatient().getEmail()
                    "",
                    "tux025@gmail.com", "tux025@gmail.com", "Envoi de la consultation a votre medecin : ",
                    "Votre consultation REF-" + consultation.getId()
                            + " a ete envoyee a votre medecin avec succes. Vous serez contacte en cas d'urgence.<br/>Ci dessous un recap de votre consultation :<br/>"
                            + "<br/>Poid : " + consultation.getParam1() + "<br/>" + "Appetit :"
                            + consultation.getParam2() + "<br/>" + "Faiblesse :" + consultation.getParam3() + "<br/>"
                            + "Douleur :" + consultation.getParam4() + "<br/>" + "Boule :" + consultation.getParam5()
                            + "<br/>" + "Fievre :" + consultation.getParam6() + "<br/>" + "Commentaire :"
                            + consultation.getCommentaire() + "<br/>" + "<br/>L'equipe vivalio Group"

            );
        }



        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide the medium to update an existing user.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable String ssoId, ModelMap model) {
        User user = userService.findBySSO(ssoId);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "registration";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssoId) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }



        userService.updateUser(user);
        Mail.sendMailRegistration("support@xxxx.net", user.getEmail(), "aa.xxxxx@gmail.com",
                "aa.xxx@gmail.com", "Modification des informations vivalio",
                "Votre utilisateur vivalio a été modifié");

        model.addAttribute("success",
                "User " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " updated successfully");
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /**
     * This method will delete an user by it's SSOID value.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-user-{ssoId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String ssoId) {
        userService.deleteUserBySSO(ssoId);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide UserProfile list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<UserProfile> initializeProfiles() {
        return userProfileService.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method will provide Docs list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("docteurs")
    public List<User> initializeAllDocs() {
        return userService.findAllDocs();
    }



    /**
     * This method handles Access-Denied redirect.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    /**
     * This method handles login GET requests. If users is already logged-in and
     * tries to goto login page again, will be redirected to list page.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method handles logout requests. Toggle the handlers if you are
     * RememberMe functionality is useless in your app.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            // new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response,
            // auth);
            persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.logout(request, response, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the principal[user-name] of logged-in user.
     */
    private String getPrincipal() {
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private User getUser() {
        String username = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        User usr = userService.findBySSO(username);
        return usr;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns true if users is already authenticated [logged-in],
     * else false.
     */
    private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }

    /**
     * This method will redirect to dashboard
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/board" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tableauBord(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
        return "board";
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your security configs and how you're quering your database to lookup the user's credentials

Comment: @J-Alex check the edited post

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891603/5898696

Comment: it worked for me and i have no more the previous error

Comment: Good news, you can post the answer and share your expirence then :)